# xcode 6: puzzling tableview cell constraints

Tags: xcode, uitableview, xcode6

My app has a number of tableviews. Each cell has a textview and sometimes a switch. I cannot get the constraints to behave consistently. 
In many cases the height of the table view cell is 98 and the height of the textview to 90 and y=8. If I attempt to Update the constraints, sometimes it wants to set both the bottom and top spaces to 8 and other times not. Sometimes it wants to adjust the height of the textview. I have been unable to see any pattern. I always set the cell height to the text height + 8.
It is very frustrating because I want all of the text views to align consistently.
What am I doing wrong? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set 4 constraints for textview

top space 
bottom space
leading space (left)

all the 3 to parent view (the cell)
and the height constraint

Comment: I set 4 constraints on each textview ... leading, trailing, top, bottom. Wouldn't setting the height be redundant (it ought to be)? But if I don't why would the behaviour be so inconsistent?

Comment: I took your advice and deleted the bottom constraint ands added a height constraints ... most of my errors went away except for one where the cell height is 98, text height is 90 and y is 8 but it expects y to be 20. (if it makes any difference it is the second cell.)

Comment: I examined the code of the offending text view and found an incorrect entry :

Comment: great :)
glad u found a solution

Comment: My comment timed out while I was examining the code of the offending text view and found an incorrect entry for heightClass=regular  <variation key="heightClass=regular" misplaced="YES">
<rect key="frame" x="20" y="0.0" width="230" height="70"/></variation> which was not visible in storyboard.  Do you think it would be safe to remove this and some others that I see.

Comment: it may appear stupid from me but make a copy of ur project and test what u want

Comment: I've done that but now I have a different constraint problem ... I'll continue and if I find out why it is happening (y=8 expected y=0) I'll report back. Thanks for your help.